# Convert string time like '18:15' to DateTime like 23/09/2010 18:15:00

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to convert `VARCHA`R time like `'18:15'` to `DateTime` like `23/09/2010 18:15:00`.
There can be any date format I just want to have date and time.

The reason is I have a column in db time of `VARCHAR(5)` type. I have input, time in string, from user. Which I want to compare like this

```
WHERE MyTable.Time < @userProvidedTime
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly you what you want but this should do the trick:

```
Declare @time varchar(10)

set @time = '18:15'

Select Cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float))as datetime) + @time
```

Answer (score 0):

Using temporal functions:

```
DECLARE @userProvidedTime AS CHAR(5);
SET @userProvidedTime = '18:15';

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 
          DATEDIFF(DAY, '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 
          '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'), 
+ CAST(@userProvidedTime AS DATETIME);
```